# What moves solve this mate in 2?

Tags: checkmate, problems

It’s White to move and mate in 2 moves.

```
[FEN "7r/1p3Q1p/2q5/3bk3/1Q2p3/2P5/r2P2PP/2KR4 w - - 0 1"]
```

Answer (score 29):

White to play checkmates in 2 with 1 d4+! exd3 e.p. 2 Qbf4#.

Black to play cannot checkmate in 2 but should win after Bxf7.

```
7r/1p3Q1p/2q5/3bk3/1Q2p3/2P5/r2P2PP/2KR4 w - - 0 1

1. d4+! exd3 2. Qbf4
```

Answer (score 7):

When normal moves don't seem to work to solve a problem, you have to look for special moves like underpromotion, castling or en passant. The latter is the case in this problem, as 1. d4+ exd3 e.p. (forced) 2. Qbf4# mates.